# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, exception, shared-libraries

I have a method that creates and calls a method from a library project.  The library method loads data from a resource.  I do this on a worker thread and NEVER touch the UI whilst doing so.  The method making the call (on a worker thread) is:

```
private void testGetXData(){

try {

    Data data = new Data();
    String xsd = data.getXSD();
    importedData = xsd;

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage(););
}

}
```

and the exception happens on the line:

```
Data data = new Data();
```

`Data` is a class in my library project. and `importedData` is a module level String.

**Edit**

I am not using a handler directly.  All I do to call the method is:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        testGetXData();
    }
}).start();
```

I do it this way so as not to block the UI thread and get the dreaded ANR message.
For completeness, I moved the resource to the library for sharing with a service.  This worked fine when the resource was in the application project.  It only now throws this exception since I moved it to the library project.

**Furthermore**

If I comment out the use of a worker thread and perform the call on the main thread, it works!  I however want to do this on a background thread, which still throws the exception.

Comment: What is the code for the `Data()` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the message tries to get the handler for current thread and fails. In order to be able to create handlers on a thread it needs a Looper and the default "Thread" implementation doesn't have one.

Extending [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) instead of Thread should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you say `new Handler()` without specifying a `Looper` it will try to get the `Looper` of the current thread. Regular worker threads don't have a looper.

The `Looper` determines which thread handles the `Message`s / executes the `Runnable`s

Either do

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

if you want to handle messages on the UI thread or create an extra thread that can handle messages. See `HandlerThread` for example here [Android ANRs from code running in a Handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368762/android-anrs-from-code-running-in-a-handler/13369215#13369215)

Note that you can't have a `Looper` inside your worker threads since a looper occupies the `run` method by waiting for new messages to process.