# How to convert a List<Object> to PagedList<Object> and vice-versa?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-jetpack

`PagedList<Object>` is used for Android's cool paging library. To make the question as minimal as possible :
If i have a list of strings like

```
  List<String> stringList; // it consists of 200 strings
```

I want to convert  `stringList` to type `PagedList<String>` like

```
  PagedList<String> pagedStringList;
```

And also if i have a `PagedList<Object>` how can convert it to a `List<Object>` ?
I went through [this for reference](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)

If i try the other way round ....

How can I convert `List<Object>` into `DataSource.Factory<Integer, Object>` ..so that indirectly i can convert it into `PagedList<>` ?

> From `DataSource.Factory<Integer, Object>` I can convert to `PagedList<>` but how can I convert `list` into `PagedList<>` ?

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Comment: will try it and let you know..i know lil kotlin though..:)

Comment: awokay :) I added the java version to be more helpful, hope it works

Answer (score 12):

I'll start with the easier part, if you want to converter a PagedList<> to a a List<> you can use the `snapshot()` method, as you can seen in the docs it retuns:

> Returns an immutable snapshot of the PagedList in its current state.A PagedList snapshot is simply an immutable shallow copy of the current state of the PagedList as a List.

Now as for the other way around you'll need to use PagedList.Builder and for that you'd need a DataSource to create the PagedList. So a avery basic dataSource that would manage your static list would look like this:

**StringDataSource.kt**

```
class StringDataSource(val provider: StringListProvider) : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, String>() {
    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Int>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, String>) {
        val list = provider.getStringList(0, params.requestedLoadSize)
        callback.onResult(list, 1, 2)
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, String>) {
        val list = provider.getStringList(params.key, params.requestedLoadSize)
        callback.onResult(list, params.key + 1)
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, String>) {
        val list = provider.getStringList(params.key, params.requestedLoadSize)
        val nextIndex = if (params.key > 1) params.key - 1 else null
        callback.onResult(list, nextIndex)
    }

    companion object {
        const val PAGE_SIZE = 20
    }
}
```

As you can see you need to override the three methods `loadInitial`, `loadAfter` and `loadBefore` in order to tell the datasource how to load the cunks of data from the list. I've wrapped you list in a provider class just for organization purposes.

**StringListProvider.kt**

```
class StringListProvider(val list: List<String>) {


    fun getStringList(page: Int, pageSize: Int): List<String> {

        val initialIndex = page * pageSize
        val finalIndex = initialIndex + pageSize
        //TODO manage index out of range
        return list.subList(initialIndex, finalIndex)
    }
}
```

To use the data source to generate the PagedList you need to build a simple configuration with `PagedList.Config.Builder`:

```
    val myConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(PAGE_SIZE)
            .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
            .build()
```

And then pass that to the `PagedList.Builder` with the datasource:

```
    val pagedStrings: PagedList<String> = PagedList.Builder<Int, String>(StringDataSource(StringListProvider(originalStrings)), myConfig)
            .setInitialKey(0)
            .build()
```

Now you have a PagedList in `pagedStrings`.

The same thing in java:

**StringListProvider.java**

```
public class StringListProvider {

    private List<String> list;

    public StringListProvider(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<String> getStringList(int page, int pageSize) {
        int initialIndex = page * pageSize;
        int finalIndex = initialIndex + pageSize;

        //TODO manage out of range index

        return list.subList(initialIndex, finalIndex);
    }
}
```

**StringDataSource.java**

```
public class StringDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, String> {

    public static final int PAGE_SIZE = 20;
    private StringListProvider provider;

    public StringDataSource(StringListProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<Integer, String> callback) {
        List<String> result = provider.getStringList(0, params.requestedLoadSize);
        callback.onResult(result, 1, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadBefore(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<Integer, String> callback) {
        List<String> result = provider.getStringList(params.key, params.requestedLoadSize);
        Integer nextIndex = null;

        if (params.key > 1) {
            nextIndex = params.key - 1;
        }
        callback.onResult(result, nextIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<Integer, String> callback) {
        List<String> result = provider.getStringList(params.key, params.requestedLoadSize);
        callback.onResult(result, params.key + 1);
    }
}
```

Config generation

```
    PagedList.Config myConfig = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(PAGE_SIZE)
            .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
            .build();
```

List convertion

```
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    StringListProvider provider = new StringListProvider(myList);
    StringDataSource dataSource = new StringDataSource(provider);
    PagedList<String> pagedStrings = new PagedList.Builder<Integer, String>(dataSource, myConfig)
            .setInitialKey(0)
            .build();
```

Comment: When you build PagedList object you need to set ```setNotifyExecutor``` and ```setFetchExecutor``` methods, otherwise crash

Comment: As nAkhmedov mentioned, you will need to set a notify and fetch executor. Here is how to create a UI thread Executor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21256419/1486374

Comment: Thank you.
Regarding the `setNotifyExecutor` and the `setFetchExecutor`, this page has a good implementation: [https://riyaz-ali.github.io/android-support-paging.html]

Answer (score 3):

I have converted a `List<Object>` to `PagedList<Object>` by this code in kotlin
i think this code can help you

1. build `config`

   ```
   private val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
           .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
           .setPageSize(LIST_SIZE)
           .build()
   ```

2.create these classes for convert and return my `PagedList<Object>`

```
     class ListDataSource<T>(private val items: List<T>) : PositionalDataSource<T>() {
            override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams, callback: LoadInitialCallback<T>) {
                callback.onResult(items, 0, items.size)
    }

            override fun loadRange(params: LoadRangeParams, callback: LoadRangeCallback<T>) {
                val start = params.startPosition
                val end = params.startPosition + params.loadSize
                callback.onResult(items.subList(start, end))
    }
}

        // UiThreadExecutor implementation example
       class UiThreadExecutor : Executor {
            private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            override fun execute(command: Runnable) {
               handler.post(command)
    }
}
```

3. Pass `val myList: List<Object>` by `config` and get `PagedList<Object>`

   ```
   val pagedList = PagedList.Builder(ListDataSource(myList), config)
                               .setNotifyExecutor(UiThreadExecutor())
                               .setFetchExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
                               .build()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve my problem, this might help.

```
val items = List<Item>.... //this can be equal to your mutable list
val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                        .setPageSize(items.size)
                        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(items.size)
                        .build()

val pagedList = PagedList.Builder(ListDataSource(items),config)
                .setNotifyExecutor (UiThreadExecutor ())
                .setFetchExecutor (AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
                .build ()


class UiThreadExecutor: Executor {
        private val handler = Handler (Looper.getMainLooper ())
        override fun execute (command: Runnable) {
            handler.post (command)
        }
    }

class ListDataSource (private val items: List<Item>): PageKeyedDataSource<Int, Item>() {
            override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Int>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, Item>) {
                callback.onResult (items, 0, items.size)
            }
    
            override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, Item>) {
    
            }
    
            override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, Item>) {
    
            }
        }
```

Other Resources: [android - how to convert list to pagedlist](https://www.tutorialfor.com/questions-92642.htm)