# How to transform a LiveData<List<X>> in LiveData<PagedList<X>>?

Tags: android, android-livedata

Is there any way I can transform an object of type `LiveData<List<X>>` to an object of type `LiveData<PagedList<X>>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as i understood you can do it in the followed way:

```
    class FirstType
    class SecondType

    val initType: LiveData<FirstType> = MutableLiveData<FirstType>()
    val resultType : LiveData<SecondType> = Transformations.map(initType, ::convertTypes)

    fun convertTypes(firstType: FirstType) : SecondType = SecondType()
```

**upd:**
What about converting `List<T>` to `PagedList<T>` try to look at:
[How to convert a List<Object> to PagedList<Object> and vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50030049/how-to-convert-a-listobject-to-pagedlistobject-and-vice-versa)

Comment: It is not about changing the type from `FirstType` to `SecondType`. The type is the same `X`. It's about transforming a `LiveData<List<X>>` in `LiveData<PagedList<X>>`, see `List<X>` into `PagedList<X>`. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Thanks for the update but `snapshot()` transforms a `PagedList<Object>` to a `List<Object> `and I need the vice-versa. Is it even possible?

Comment: In the answer from the link, after `snapshot()` explanation, starting from `Now as for the other way around...` is it not what you need?

Comment: Let me check again and I get back to you.